# Delegation coding style?

Tags: objective-c

I have just a minor question about coding style.

I have a subclass of `UIViewController` which is a delegate to an `MKMapView` object. Naturally, I have an ivar in my view controller which points to said `MKMapView`. When I'm writing one of the callback methods `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`, is it smarter to send messages to the passed-in reference of the map view or to the ivar reference of the map view?

I'm aware these are essentially the same thing. I use the ivar reference of the map view object. What are the pros and cons of both styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that both `MKMapView` objects are one and the same thing, it doesn't matter in this particular case. The reason for the convention requiring the first delegate parameter to be the calling object is to handle the situation when a class is a delegate to more than one object. E.g. if you show two different `UIAlertView`'s in your view controller, and the view controller is a delegate to both (a common scenario), then you want to know in the delegate methods which alert view you're dealing with.

Comment: So it's a good idea to get in the habit of using the passed-in reference.

Comment: I guess it's more consistent this way. A matter of personal style :)

Comment: When it really doesn't matter, remember reusability and readability.